# Update aggregate columns inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

Consider a stored procedure that updates aggregate data for a specified `phone_id` on a specific day `call_date`.

```
create proc phone_calls_aggregate @phone_id int, @call_date date
as
begin
    -- check if aggregate table already exists
    if not exists (select * from sys.sysobjects 
                   where name = 'tbl_calls_agg')    
        create table tbl_calls_agg ( -- create table to store aggregate data
            phone_id int,
            call_date date,
            total_charge money,
            total_duration int
         )

     --update aggregate data
     update tbl_calls_agg 
     -- update aggregate columns
     where phone_id = @phone_id and call_date = @call_date
end
go
```

The columns `phone_id and`call_date will be passed in as parameters. The other columns should contain aggregate data computed from another table `tbl_calls.` **Can I update these columns in a conventional `UPDATE` statement?**

The query to originally insert aggregate data is:

```
select
    phone_id as [Phone Number], 
    call_date as [Call Date]     
    sum(charge) as [Total charge], 
    count(duration) as [Total Calls Duration]
from 
    tbl_calls
where 
    phone_id = @phone_id and call_date = @day
group by 
    phone_id, call_date
```

More specifically, `sum(charge)` and `count(duration)`  are the desired aggregates.

Comment: If the table doesn't exist and you create it, updating it isn't of much use I guess. So you should maybe check if the `@phone_id` exists?

Comment: You're right. I wanted to post the structure of the aggregate table, for the record/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MERGE` statement is designed for this type of work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE phone_calls_aggregate @phone_id int, @call_date date
AS
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects 
               WHERE name = 'tbl_calls_agg')    
    CREATE TABLE tbl_calls_agg (
        phone_id INT,
        call_date DATE,
        total_charge MONEY,
        total_duration INT
     )

MERGE INTO tbl_calls_agg d
USING ( SELECT
            phone_id, 
            call_date     
            sum(charge) AS total_charge, 
            COUNT(duration) AS total_duration
        FROM tbl_calls
        WHERE phone_id = @phone_id AND call_date = @day
        GROUP BY phone_id, call_date
      ) s
ON d.phone_id = s.phone_id AND d.call_date = s.call_date
WHEN MATCHED AND (d.total_charge <> s.total_charge 
                  OR d.total_duration <> s.total_duration) THEN
    UPDATE SET d.total_charge = s.total_charge, d.total_duration = s.total_duration
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT
    VALUES ( phone_id, call_date, total_charge, total_duration )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN   
    DELETE;

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
CREATE PROC phone_calls_aggregate @phone_id INT
    ,@call_date DATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- check if aggregate table already exists
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.sysobjects
            WHERE NAME = 'tbl_calls_agg'
            )
        CREATE TABLE tbl_calls_agg (
            -- create table to store aggregate data
            phone_id INT
            ,call_date DATE
            ,total_charge MONEY
            ,total_duration INT
            )


    --update aggregate data
            ;

    WITH Agg_Data
    AS (
        SELECT phone_id AS [Phone Number]
            ,call_date AS [Call Date] sum(charge) AS [Total charge]
            ,count(duration) AS [Total Calls Duration]
        FROM tbl_calls
        WHERE phone_id = @phone_id
            AND call_date = @day
        GROUP BY phone_id
            ,call_date
        )


    UPDATE tbl
    SET total_charge = agg.[Total charge]
        ,total_duration = agg.[Total Calls Duration]
    FROM tbl_calls_agg tbl
    JOIN Agg_Data agg ON tbl.phone_id = agg.[Phone Number]
        AND tbl.call_date = agg.[Call Date]
END
GO
```

Do you need to keep any record of what the values were before the update was applied? In this scenario I would use insert instead and a flag to mark already existing occurrences of the number/date as old.

Finally, you might want to consider handling dates explicitly as they are always a pain at some point.

Comment: No need to keep the values stored before the Update.

Answer (score 0):

If the aggregrate values are already inserted by your query.There is no difference between a column with individual or aggregate value.You can  update the columns normally.Only consideration you should have are functional ones

```
update tbl_calls_agg 
     set total_charge=1000,
         total_duration=100
     where phone_id = @phone_id and call_date = @call_date
```

Comment: The inserted values must not be hardcoded,  but picked up from the other table!